# Querying ContentWorkSpace as a community portal user results 0 rows

Tags: contentdocument, content

I have an apex controller for an aura components that is suppose to query ContentWorkSpace object to get the workspace Id. But the issue is, it results in 0 rows when it runs as community portal user. Running the below statement as an anonymous user in dev console, results in 1 row. Any thoughts please?

ID workspaceId = [SELECT Id FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = 'EMEA Sales'][0].Id;

Comment: is the portal user a member of the Library?

Comment: yes @cropredy, portal users have already been added to a public group and we have added the public group to the library with Viewer access.

Comment: Are they CRM Content Users? (As defined on the User record)